# Property of uniformly continuous semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

let $A$ be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $t \mapsto e^{tA}$ denote the associated uniformly continuous semigroup, we may also assume that $\|e^{tA}\| \leq 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Does the equality ($x \in H$)
$$\|e^{tA}x\|^2 = (x, e^{2tA}x)$$ hold even if $A$ is not necessarily self-adjoint? My textbook seems to claim this is true, but I fail to see why it should be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what textbook is this?

Comment: "James Glimm, Arthur Jaffe" - Quantum Physics
But what I asked isn't acutally claimed there, there was just no explanation why $A$ should be self-adjoint.  What I overlooked is that if you have a contraction semigroup, its generator must be negative, therefore self-adjoint which also makes $e^{tA}$ self-adjoint.

Comment: The semigroup in my example is a contraction semigroup, but not self-adjoint.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland you are right, I have misread a theorem there. I'm going to have to find another explanation then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this did hold, then
$$
              (e^{tA}x,e^{tA}x)=(x,e^{2tA}x) \\
           \frac{d}{dt}(e^{tA}x,e^{tA}x)=\frac{d}{dt}(x,e^{2tA}x) \\
               (e^{tA}Ax,e^{tA}x)+(e^{tA}x,e^{tA}Ax)=(x,e^{2tA}2Ax)
$$
Setting $t=0$ would then give
$$
                    (Ax,x)+(x,Ax)=(x,2Ax), \\
                    (Ax,x)=(x,Ax),\;\;\; x \in H.
$$

Comment: i believe you have a typo in the third line, i guess it should be $(x,e^{2tA}2Ax)$

Comment: @user159517 : Thanks. I corrected that typo just now.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to have a few  easy examples of semigroups to check such things out. For example, on $H=\mathbb{R}^2$ the semigroup $e^{tA}=\pmatrix{\cos(t)&\sin(t)\\-\sin(t)&\cos(t)}$ satisfies $\|e^{tA}\|\leq 1$. But at time $t=\pi/2$ we have 
$(x,e^{2tA}x)=-\|x\|$ which is strictly negative if $\|x\|>0.$